# Class 'phone ' not found while implementing eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is the first time i am trying to use eloquent relationship.I have a **userModel** and a **phoneModel** class.They represents **users** and **phone** table respectively. Here i am trying to access The phone number of a user when he/she logged in.

> users table has the field (id,name,password) and phone table has the
>   (field id,phone_no,user_id)

**phone migration is below:**

```
public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('phone',function(Blueprint $table){
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('phone_no',20);
       $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

i applied `hasOne` and `belongs to` relationship on both models:

**userModel.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
class userModel extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    //
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function phone(){
             $this->hasOne('App\Models\phone');
    }

}
```

**phoneModel.php:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class phoneModel extends Model
    {
        //
        protected $table='phone';
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('users');
        }
    }
```

***Now when i tried to get a phone number from logged user i get an error called class 'phone' not found***

Here is the code inside show method of userController:

```
public function show($user)
{
    //
    $indicator=is_numeric($user)?'id':'name';
    $info=userModel::where($indicator,'=',$user)->get()->first();
    if($info){
       $phone = userModel::find($info->id)->phone;
       $data=array('info'=>$info,'phone'=>$phone);
       return View::make('user.show')->with($data);
    }else{
      $info=userModel::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->name)->get()->first();
      return View::make('user.show')->with('user',$info);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would make your life a lot easier if you followed some basic conventions, i.e. class names should start with a capital letter (`Phone` and not `phone`). The `Model` suffix is unneccesary (`Phone` rather than `phoneModel`); and table names should be pluralised (`phones` not just `phone`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your phone class `phoneModel` but you added the relationship as `$this->hasOne('App\Models\phone');`.  You also created those classes in the `App` namespace but referenced them as `App\Models\class`.

The standard practice is to name your model classes after the model and using uppercase letters.  So your classes would be called `User` and `Phone` rather than `userModel` and `phoneModel`.  And the database tables would be `users` and `phones`.  If you use these standards, Laravel will take care of a lot of things automatically behind the scenes.

**User class**

```
namespace App;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
//
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

//Laravel will assume the User model is in the table `users` so you don't need to specify

public function phone(){
         $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

**Phone Class**

```
namespace App;

class Phone extends Model
{
    //Laravel will assume the Phone model is in the table `phones` so you don't need to specify
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Comment: Is there any problem using eloquent relationship with a model name of userModel or phoneModel ?How i can use those name in my code..you changed the class name

Comment: no, you can use `return $this->belongsTo('App\userModel');` and `$this->hasOne('App\phoneModel');`.  These will work.  But changing table and class names will make things easier for you.  It is best practice for all PHP code to use capital name for classes.